# Decrease the debug startup time of the python code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to decrease the debug startup time of the python script in visual studio code? If I a have a lot of import library (like opencv, numpy, pandas and so on) every time i start the debug of the script, pressing the F5 button, the environment wait for seconds to reload them. Is it possible to reduce this time? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There's no explicit technique to improving the import time short of using lazy loading, but there are technical considerations which have to be taken into account before going down that route (e.g. some modules simply don't work when loaded lazily).